# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed. While running in Powershell

Tags: powershell, db2

I'm new to Power shell and in my case i'm trying to execute a Select query in Db2 and then exporting that result to a csv file. I'm trying to achieve this by using power shell. But while executing i'm getting the error "Exception calling "GetFactory" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be
installed." I have checked the config files in the framework and made sure all the entries are there for IBM db2 in the Dbproviderfactory tag. I have also executed the below commands provided by IBM docs to make sure the entries happened correctly

db2nmpsetup -l c:\db2nmpsetup.log

```
$extractFile = 'D:\Lease_CSV.csv'
$factory = [System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories]::GetFactory('IBM.Data.DB2')
$cstrbld = $factory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder()
$cstrbld.Database = '********'
$cstrbld.UserID = '********'
$cstrbld.Password = '*******'
$cstrbld.Server = '*********'

$dbconn = $factory.CreateConnection()
$dbconn.ConnectionString = $cstrbld.ConnectionString
$dbconn.Open()
$dbcmd = $dbconn.CreateCommand()
$dbcmd.CommandText = 'select
T1.ROW_NUM,
T5.DETAIL_TYPE_CD,
T1.ADMIN_FEES_TICKET,
T1.ADMINISTRATIVE_FEES,
T1.BASE_RENT,
T1.CITATIONS,
T1.COLLECTION_REPO_FEES,
T1.DESC,
T1.EFFECTIVE_DATE,
T1.LATE_CHARGE,
T1.MISC_FEE,
T2.STATUS_CD,
T4.ROW_ID,
T3.ROW_ID,
T2.BUILD,
T1.REVERSE_FLG,
T1.NSF_FLG,
T2.PR_CON_ID,
T1.PROC_DATE,
T1.PROPERTY_TAX,
T1.REGISTRATION_FEES,
T1.REPAIR_FEES,
T1.SALES_TAX,
T1.TERMINATION_FEES,
T1.TOTAL_TRANS,
T1.TRANSACTION_TYPE

FROM
SIEBEL.LSE_INPHIST_VIEW T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET T2 ON T1.ACCOUNT_NUM = T2.ASSET_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET_CON T3 ON T2.ROW_ID = T3.ASSET_ID AND
T3.RELATION_TYPE_CD = "Obligor"
LEFT OUTER JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSETCON_ADDR T4 ON T3.ROW_ID = T4.ASSET_CON_ID AND T4.USE_TYPE_CD = "Bill To"
LEFT OUTER JOIN SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT T5 ON T2.PROD_ID = T5.ROW_ID
WHERE
(T1.ACNT_ID = 01003501435)
ORDER BY
T1.ACNT_ID DESC,T1.PROC_DATE DESC WITH UR'
$rdr = $dbcmd.ExecuteReader()
$dt =[System.Data.DataTable]::New()
$dt.Load($rdr)
$dbconn.Close()

$dt | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Do you see your DB2 providor factory if you run `[System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories]::GetFactoryClasses()` on the command line?

Comment: How can we run that on Command line?

Comment: By command line I mean in Powershell  and it is run as is in my example.

Comment: It's not showing anything.